# Python gui and realtime update

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, matplotlib-3d

I have written a multi thread code that creates a 3d cube and then rotates it. What i want to do is that the GUI loads up with initial cube and then after few seconds second rotated cube is shown....kind of some animation

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time
import threading

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Define the vertices of the cube

p1 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
p2 = np.array([1, 0, 0])
p3 = np.array([1, 1, 0])
p4 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
p5 = np.array([0, 0, 1])
p6 = np.array([1, 0, 1])
p7 = np.array([1, 1, 1])
p8 = np.array([0, 1, 1])

# Define the rotation angle in degrees




def thread_function_1():
    print("Thread 1 starting...")
    ax.plot([p1[0], p2[0]], [p1[1], p2[1]], [p1[2], p2[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p2[0], p3[0]], [p2[1], p3[1]], [p2[2], p3[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p3[0], p4[0]], [p3[1], p4[1]], [p3[2], p4[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p4[0], p1[0]], [p4[1], p1[1]], [p4[2], p1[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p5[0], p6[0]], [p5[1], p6[1]], [p5[2], p6[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p6[0], p7[0]], [p6[1], p7[1]], [p6[2], p7[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p7[0], p8[0]], [p7[1], p8[1]], [p7[2], p8[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p8[0], p5[0]], [p8[1], p5[1]], [p8[2], p5[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p5[0], p1[0]], [p5[1], p1[1]], [p5[2], p1[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p6[0], p2[0]], [p6[1], p2[1]], [p6[2], p2[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p7[0], p3[0]], [p7[1], p3[1]], [p7[2], p3[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p8[0], p4[0]], [p8[1], p4[1]], [p8[2], p4[2]], 'k-')

def thread_function_2():
    print("Thread 2 starting...")
    theta_x = 45

# Define the rotation matrix
    rotation_matrix_x = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                                  [0, np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta_x)), -np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta_x))],
                                  [0, np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta_x)), np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta_x))]])

    # Rotate the vertices of the cube using the rotation matrix
    global p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8
    p1 = rotation_matrix_x.dot(p1)
    p2 = rotation_matrix_x.dot(p2)
    p3 = rotation_matrix_x.dot(p3)
    p4 = rotation_matrix_x.dot(p4)
    p5 = rotation_matrix_x.dot(p5)
    p6 = rotation_matrix_x.dot(p6)
    p7 = rotation_matrix_x.dot(p7)
    p8 = rotation_matrix_x.dot(p8)

    # Plot the rotated cube
    ax.plot([p1[0], p2[0]], [p1[1], p2[1]], [p1[2], p2[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p2[0], p3[0]], [p2[1], p3[1]], [p2[2], p3[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p3[0], p4[0]], [p3[1], p4[1]], [p3[2], p4[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p4[0], p1[0]], [p4[1], p1[1]], [p4[2], p1[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p5[0], p6[0]], [p5[1], p6[1]], [p5[2], p6[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p6[0], p7[0]], [p6[1], p7[1]], [p6[2], p7[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p7[0], p8[0]], [p7[1], p8[1]], [p7[2], p8[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p8[0], p5[0]], [p8[1], p5[1]], [p8[2], p5[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p5[0], p1[0]], [p5[1], p1[1]], [p5[2], p1[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p6[0], p2[0]], [p6[1], p2[1]], [p6[2], p2[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p7[0], p3[0]], [p7[1], p3[1]], [p7[2], p3[2]], 'k-')
    ax.plot([p8[0], p4[0]], [p8[1], p4[1]], [p8[2], p4[2]], 'k-')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function_1)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function_2)

    t1.start()
    
    time.sleep(2)
    t2.start()
    plt.show()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

what is happening is that when i run the code it waits for 2 sec (as per my delay) and then shows both cubes together. what mistake i am doing in this code